# Updating tables in SQL Server from an Android app

Tags: android, json, wcf, sql-server-2008

I am currently developing an Android app that gets details from an SQL Server table. Thanks to everyone who has helped previously with my understanding of AsyncTasks and JSON, I can now retrieve objects. However, my attempt at updating tables from an Android device is not so smooth.

Firstly, I'll begin with the table:
I have a JobStatus table that is populated by a trigger that runs as a new record is entered into the Jobs table. When the trigger is run, these 4 columns are populated, namely:-

- The JobStatusID
- The JobID
- QLSJobID
- JobType

The remaining 4 however, are null by default and are expected to be updated through the Android app operations. They are:-

- Latitude
- Longitude
- TimeComplete
- DateComplete

I have adapted a WCF web service obtained from [here](http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page3.htm) to do the operations. It is essentially a POST update operation.

Now, for the Android code. Essentially, what happens at the Android app is that a JobStatus entry is updated only when the Save/Sign button is captured. For that to happen, the user must input their name and sign for a Job for all the information to be sent back to the JobStatus table. Here is the code:

```
package com.signonglass;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONStringer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CaptureSignature extends Activity implements LocationListener
{
    private final static String getJobURI = "http://192.168.0.105:8095/CentralMonitoring/CentralMonitor.svc/getJobStatus/";
    private final static String jobURI = "http://192.168.0.105:8095/CentralMonitoring/CentralMonitor.svc/UpdateJobStatus";

    final Date currentTime = new Date();
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss a z"); 

    //Live Connections
    //private final static String jobURI = "http://192.168.14.9:8092/CentralMonitoring/CentralMonitor.svc/UpdateJobStatus";
    //private final static String getJobURI = "http://192.168.14.9:8092/CentralMonitoring/CentralMonitor.svc/getJobStatus/";
    JSONStringer jobStatToUpdate;
    LinearLayout mContent;
    signature mSignature;
    Button mClear, mGetSign, mCancel;
    public static String tempDir;
    public int count = 1;
    public String current = null;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    View mView;
    File mypath;

    //additional variables for capturing details
    Consignments cObj;
    public Handler mHandler;
    JobStatus js = new JobStatus();
    JobStatus jsUpdate;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    String datetime;
    TextView tvLoc;
    Location location;
    String transAdd;

    private String uniqueId;
    private EditText yourName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signature);

        cObj = (Consignments)this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Consignment");
        //tempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir) + "/";

        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir(getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        prepareDirectory();

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

        uniqueId = cObj.getJobType() + Integer.toString(cObj.getConsignmentID());

        current = uniqueId + ".jpg";
        mypath = new File(directory, current);

        //Control Properties
        mContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.signing);
        mSignature = new signature(this, null);
        mSignature.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mContent.addView(mSignature, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
        mGetSign = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getsign);
        mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
        mCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        mView = mContent;

        yourName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourName);

        /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        String provider = mlocManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        location = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, CaptureSignature.this);
        tvLoc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tvLoc.setText("Latitude: "+ location.getLatitude() +", Longitude: "+ location.getLongitude());



        mClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {        
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Cleared");
                mSignature.clear();
                mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        mGetSign.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {        
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Saved");
                boolean error = captureSignature();
                if(!error)
                {
                    new updateJobStatus().execute(js);
                    mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    mSignature.save(mView);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("status", "done");
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
                    finish(); 
                }
            }
        });

        //Cancel method - to create pop up button 
        mCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {        
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Canceled");
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("status", "cancel");
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtras(b);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);  
                finish();
            }
        });

        new getJobStatus().execute(uniqueId);
    }

    public class getJobStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, JobStatus>
    {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CaptureSignature.this);
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String theString = "";
        StringBuilder builder;

        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Getting " + uniqueId +" to be updated...");
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener()
            {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0)
                {
                    getJobStatus.this.cancel(true);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected JobStatus doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            try
            {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String theString = new String("");
                //http get request
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(getJobURI + cObj.getJobType() + cObj.getConsignmentID());
                //set the hedear to get the data in JSON format
                request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                //get the response
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                is.close();

                theString = builder.toString();

                JSONObject jsObj = new JSONObject(theString);
                JSONArray jstat = jsObj.getJSONArray("getJobStatusResult");

                for(int i = 0; i < jstat.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jst = jstat.getJSONObject(i);
                    js.JobStatusID = jst.getInt("JobStatusID");
                    js.JobID = jst.getInt("JobID");
                    js.JobType = jst.getString("jobType");
                    js.QlsJobID = jst.getInt("qlsJobID");
                    /*js.DateComplete = jst.getString("dateComplete");
                    js.TimeComplete = jst.getString("timeComplete");
                    js.Latitude = jst.getDouble("latitude");
                    js.Longitude = jst.getDouble("longitude");*/
                }   
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return js;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JobStatus jobStatus)
        {
            this.progressDialog.dismiss();
            jsUpdate = js;
        }
    }


    public class updateJobStatus extends AsyncTask<JobStatus, String, JSONStringer>
    {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CaptureSignature.this);
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String theString = "";
        StringBuilder builder;

        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Updating " + uniqueId +"...");
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener()
            {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0)
                {
                    updateJobStatus.this.cancel(true);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONStringer doInBackground(JobStatus... arg0)
        {
            HttpPut request = new HttpPut(jobURI);

            try
            {
                    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("AEST"));
                    jobStatToUpdate = new JSONStringer()
                    .object()
                    .key("JobStatusID").value(js.getJobStatusID())
                    .key("JobID").value(js.getJobID())
                    .key("dateComplete").value(js.getDate())
                    .key("latitude").value(js.getLat())
                    .key("longitude").value(js.getClass())
                    .key("timeComplete").value(js.getTime())
                    .key("qlsjobID").value(js.getQLSID())
                    .endObject();

                    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jobStatToUpdate.toString());
                    request.setEntity(entity);

                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

                Log.d("WebInvoke", "Saving : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()); 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jobStatToUpdate;
        }


    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        //Log.w("GetSignature", "onDestory");
        //super.onDestroy();
    }

    private boolean captureSignature()
    {

        boolean error = false;
        String errorMessage = "";


        if(yourName.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            errorMessage = errorMessage + "Please enter your Name\n";
            error = true;
        }   

        if(error)
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 105, 50);
            toast.show();
        }

        return error;
    }

    private boolean prepareDirectory() 
    {
        try
        {
            if (makedirs()) 
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not initiate File System.. Is Sdcard mounted properly?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean makedirs() 
    {
        File tempdir = new File(tempDir);
        if (!tempdir.exists())
            tempdir.mkdirs();

        if (tempdir.isDirectory()) 
        {
            File[] files = tempdir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) 
            {
                if (!file.delete()) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Failed to delete " + file);
                }
            }
        }
        return (tempdir.isDirectory());
    }

    public class signature extends View 
    {
        private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
        private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        private Path path = new Path();

        private float lastTouchX;
        private float lastTouchY;
        private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

        public signature(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
        {
            super(context, attrs);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        }

        public void save(View v) 
        {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Width: " + v.getWidth());
            Log.v("log_tag", "Height: " + v.getHeight());
            if(mBitmap == null)
            {
                mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);;
            }
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            try
            {
                FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

                v.draw(canvas); 
                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream); 
                mFileOutStream.flush();
                mFileOutStream.close();
                String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "title", null);
                Log.v("log_tag","url: " + url);

            }
            catch(Exception e) 
            { 
                Log.v("log_tag", e.toString()); 
            } 
        }

        public void clear() 
        {
            path.reset();
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
        {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
        {
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();
            mGetSign.setEnabled(true);

            switch (event.getAction()) 
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                lastTouchX = eventX;
                lastTouchY = eventY;
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
                int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) 
                {
                    float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                    float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                    expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
                    path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
                }
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;

            default:
                debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
                return false;
            }

            invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

            lastTouchX = eventX;
            lastTouchY = eventY;

            return true;
        }

        private void debug(String string)
        {

        }

        private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) 
        {
            if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left) 
            {
                dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
            } 
            else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right) 
            {
                dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
            }

            if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top) 
            {
                dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
            } 
            else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom) 
            {
                dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
            }
        }

        private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) 
        {
            dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
            dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
            dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
            dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location mlocation)
    {
        tvLoc.setText("Latitude: "+ location.getLatitude() +", Longitude: "+ location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

The code here is a combination of what I got from [here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/11/android-capture-signature-using-canvas.html), with some modifications. I have commented some stuff out - it may contribute to the error, but at this point, I'm more obsessed with updating the JobStatus object.

And I'm sure that the code above, most notably the UpdateJobTask AsyncTask needs to be fixed heavily.

I haven't had any errors running this, but here is the error log either way:-

```
05-29 10:33:37.214: W/dalvikvm(17704): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f13258)
05-29 10:33:37.226: E/AndroidRuntime(17704): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 10:33:37.226: E/AndroidRuntime(17704): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.signonglass/com.signonglass.CaptureSignature} did not call through to super.onDestroy()
05-29 10:33:37.226: E/AndroidRuntime(17704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
05-29 10:33:37.226: E/AndroidRuntime(17704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3289)
05-29 10:33:37.226: E/AndroidRuntime(17704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:134)
05-29 10:33:37.226: E/AndroidRuntime(17704):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
05-29 10:33:37.226: E/AndroidRuntime(17704):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-29 10:33:37.226: E/AndroidRuntime(17704):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
05-29 10:33:37.226: E/AndroidRuntime(17704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
05-29 10:33:37.226: E/AndroidRuntime(17704):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 10:33:37.226: E/AndroidRuntime(17704):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 10:33:37.226: E/AndroidRuntime(17704):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
05-29 10:33:37.226: E/AndroidRuntime(17704):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
05-29 10:33:37.226: E/AndroidRuntime(17704):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance for your tips and suggestions guys! :)

Comment: @codeMagic, have you encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error log, you should call super.onDestroy() in your onDestroy().

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've enabled it.